# print to string or convert AnyObject to string swift Azure

Tags: string, swift, printing, stream

I invoke an API and after the answer call my method

```
func getLikes(result:AnyObject!, response:NSHTTPURLResponse! , error:NSError!){

    println(result)

}
```

And when I try print "result" - I get normal JSON in console, but when I try to convert to String

```
var t = result as String
```

- have "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS".

I try to do print to targetStream (like NSOutputStream), but I don't find how to do it.

How to convert json to string, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i find solution:

If some tyype you can print, but don't know what it is - object implementation Printable interface([printable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Printable.html)) 
 So, you can do that:

```
var t:String = result.description
```

And all, good day